# How to generate a random vector with fixed sum and bounded elements

Tags: vectors, random-variables, constraints, random-matrices

How we can generate a random vector $E =[e_1, e_2,e_3.\dots, e_N] \in R^N$ such that  $\sum_i^N e_i = T \;$  and  $ 0 \le e_ i \le d_i$    $\forall i \in 1,2,3,\dots,N$ where  $d_i$  specifies the upper bound on each element of the vector. Is this problem over constrained? if yes, any guidance to for relaxation.

Comment: What kind of "random" generation do you need? Uniformly over all possible vectors, with respect to the usual measure on $\Bbb R^N$? Is the following procedure good enough for your purposes?: select $e_1,\dots,e_{N-1}$ randomly from their intervals $[0,d_i]$, set $e_N = T - (e_1+\cdots+e_{N-1})$, accept if $e_N\in[0,d_N]$, otherwise throw the values away and try again.

Comment: thanks for response. I need uniformly distributed numbers and need them for use in an evolutionary algorithms. So, need to generate them many times and in shortest time. I am trying to time this solution.

Comment: Hint: you question in $\mathbb R^2$ is to generate uniformly random points on a segment of the line $x+y=T$. Change variable $(x,y)\mapsto z$ so that it becomes $z\in[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks all for help. I posted the question another platform and was discussed at length by experts. I am linking the responses here if they can benefit somebody. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/506256-how-to-generate-a-random-vector-with-fixed-sum-and-bounded-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious necessary condition is to have $\sum_{i=1}^N d_i \ge T$.

If you don't care about choosing uniformly, the simplest is to generate $N$ random numbers $0 \le r_i \le d_i$, and compute $R = \sum_{i=1}^N r_i$.

In the case $R<T$, increase the $e_i$ one by one to their maximum until the $\sum_{i=1}^N e_i = T$ as needed. The procedure is guaranteed to work if $\sum_{i=1}^N d_i \ge T$.

Otherwise (if $R > T$), then set $e_i = T r_i/R$. Then, by construction,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{T r_i}{R}
 = \frac{T}{R} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i
 = T.
$$

Comment: The first procedure you outline does not produce a uniform distribution on the set of possibilities. For example, assumine $N=2$ and $d_1=d_2=T$. Then $(T,0)$ is much less likely than $(T/2,T/2)$, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin +1, agree, made the changes to the answer.